# How to fix the anchor and h1 in css?

Tags: html, css

I have an html with markup,

```
<a class="home-link" href="index.html" rel="home">
<h1 class="site-title">John Arellano's Personal Website</h1>
</a>
```

I have a problem in Styling this Site-title. My Cursor allow me to Click to 
the link even it is in the blank space.

Can anyone help me fix this using CSS? Because I can't change the HTML Document. So I am hoping to fix it with CSS Only.

I can still click the link.. If the  width is 200px; i can still click in the position greater than 200px;

Comment: Could you be more clear what exactly you want to do?

Comment: use `cursor:default`  where ever u don't need the click option

Comment: I already edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with css as follows:

```
<style>
     a:link{display:inline-block;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

block element can not be placed inside the inline element, this is a mistake! it should look like this:

```
<h1 class="site-title"><a class="home-link" href="index.html" rel="home">John Arellano's Personal Website</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the html code like this:

```
<h1><a href="" class="home-link">Site name</a></h1>
```

Instead try this. Probably you have indentation in your css. Try use that:

```
a.home-link{
 text-indent:0;
 display:block;
 cursor:pointer;
 height:80px; /*adjust your height */
 width:80px; /*adjust your width */

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My Situation is, I can't change the HTML Code.  And I Tried your css but still not working

Comment: Can you please be more clear about your ques. Or do you have a online link for the page?